# "ERROR unspecified algorithm" when signing a PDF with itextsharp 5.5.13.2 and SHA-256

Tags: pdf, itext, signature, sha1, sha256

Good morning, I am trying to sign a PDF document using ItextSharp 5.5.13.2 and SHA-256 for the signature process but at the moment of signing I get the error "Specified Algorithm is Invalid". This error does not happen when I use SHA-1 with .NetFramework 4.7.2 to sign the PDF, the next method is the one I use to sign the PDF.

```
    public void SignPDF(string PathSourceDoc, string PathTargetDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate, string pathLogo)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PathSourceDoc))
        using (var writer = new FileStream(PathTargetDoc, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, writer, '\0', null, true))
        {


            var signature = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            signature.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;
            signature.Reason = "My Reason";
            signature.Location = "My Location";
            signature.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
            signature.Acro6Layers = true;

            PdfSignature objSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
            objSignature.Date = new PdfDate(signature.SignDate);
            signature.CryptoDictionary = objSignature;

            var bcCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);
            string name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("CN");
            string industry = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("O");
            string position = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(bcCert).GetField("T");
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

            signature.Layer2Text = "Digital Signed by: " + name + "\n" +
                                   "Reason: " + "My Reason" + "\n" +
                                   "Date: " + date;
            signature.Layer2Font = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8);

            Image img = Image.GetInstance(pathLogo);
            signature.SignatureGraphic = img;

            signature.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 300, 110);
            signature.SetVisibleSignature(rect, 1, null);
            var standard = CryptoStandard.CADES;

            /*I tried this way but I get an error of type Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported.'*/
            X509Certificate cert = certificate;
            X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
            var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(signatureCert.PrivateKey).Private;// the error is generated in this line (Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported.').
            IExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");
            /****************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

            X509Certificate2Signature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1); /*throws an exception on this line of type "System.ArgumentException: 'Unknown encryption algorithm System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng'" 
                                                                                                                              * when using .NET Core 3.1. this always happens, it doesn't matter if I use sha1 or use any other algorithm, it always generates error*/


            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signature, externalSignature, new[] { bcCert }, null, null, null, 0, standard);
        }
    }
```

The method receives as input parameters the path of the PDF that I need to sign, the path of the pdf that will be created when signing, the certificate and the path of the logo for displaying the image in the signature. Actually I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I've been researching related questions and it should work with SHA-1 and SHA-256 and .NetFramework.

Then I migrated the project to .NetCore 3.1 in order to try to fix the problem but instead I got a new error (It is commented in the code). My goal is to use .NetCore and to allow me to sign a pdf using sha256. I have no problem modifying the SignPdf method in order to make the program work.
Any contribution or information link is appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Psdt: This is the stacktrace is as follows...

[image: FullStackTrace]

this is the stacktrace image of the error when the project was migrated to .Net Core 3.1 [image: StackTrace_NetCore]

Comment: What signing algorithms does your private key support? And please share the full stack trace.

Comment: Hello @mkl , thank you very much for helping me, I edited the question adding the stacktrace and the algorithm that the key supports is "sha256RSA" and the signature hash agorithm is "sha256". I got this information directly from the certificate I am using, the program throws the error in the line where it makes the MakeSignature.SignDetached

Comment: @mkl I edited the question, is that what you requested?

Comment: Yes. But it baffles me. `X509Certificate2Signature.Sign` calls `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData` for `"SHA256"`. That method of the Microsoft crypto APIs apparently does know that algorithm because before forwarding the call to `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash` (where the exception occurs) it had to calculate the hash value. After forwarding the calculated hash to `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash`, though, this method of the Microsoft crypto APIs apparently does _not_ know that algorithm. Hhmmm, but that indeed appears to be documented.

Comment: @mkl I migrated the program from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Core 3.1 to see if the problem could be fixed that way (I edited the question code and added the new error call stack) but now I run into the problem that it does not let me sign with any algorithm and ends up generating an error in the line of the X509Certificate2Signature object receiving an error of type "System.ArgumentException: 'Unknown encryption algorithm System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng'". Is there a way to do the signature using sha256 with .NetCore 3.1? By the way thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, as said in my answer, one should replace `X509Certificate2Signature` by another `IExternalSignature` using the newer Microsoft cryptography framework.

Answer (score 0):

*Apparently the Microsoft Crypto APIs used by `X509Certificate2Signature` do not support SHA-256.*

You use a `X509Certificate2Signature` instance as `IExternalSignature` argument of `MakeSignature.SignDetached`.

If the `PrivateKey` of your `X509Certificate2` is a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` (which appears to be the case for your certificate), `X509Certificate2Signature.Sign` calls

```c#
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
return rsa.SignData(message, hashAlgorithm);
```

`RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData` at first apparently does support `"SHA256"` because before forwarding execution to `SignHash` it must have calculated the hash value to sign.

`RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash`, though, does not support SHA-256, according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signhash) on that method:

> #### Remarks
>
> This method creates a digital signature that is verified using the VerifyHash method.
>
> The valid hash algorithms are SHA1 and MD5. The algorithm identifier can be derived from the hash name by using the MapNameToOID method.
>
> Due to collision problems with SHA1 and MD5, Microsoft recommends a security model based on SHA256 or better.

*(Viewed 2021-06-24, 11:07)*

Thus, you get the *"Specified Algorithm is Invalid"* error.

Essentially, therefore, one should not base one's `IExternalSignature` implementation for RSA signing on `RSACryptoServiceProvider` anymore.

Maybe this is why `X509Certificate2Signature` was not ported to iText version 7...

An alternative approach might be to check whether the `PrivateKey` is a `RSACng` first and in that case use it as a `RSACng`. This *Cryptography Next Generation (CNG)* implementation of the RSA algorithm should support better hashing algorithms...